# Aligning Icon Images with Title Below

Tags: html, css

I need to edit these icon kind of menu.

I need them centered on the page, and also look good on mobile.

Here is my sample code:

```
<div style="margin-left: 0 auto;">

  <div style="margin:0 auto;"> <a href="http://kutsalkitap.org/category/tartisma/"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-107" src="http://kutsalkitap.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Blog-Icon.png" alt="tartisma-blog" width="128" height="128" /><br />Tartışma <br />Blog</a></div>

  <div style="margin:0 auto;"><a href="http://kutsalkitap.org/kaynaklar/"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-107" src="http://kutsalkitap.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Gift-Icon.png" alt="hediyeler-kaynaklar" width="128" height="128" /><br />Hediyeler <br />ve Kaynaklar</a></div>

  <div style="margin:0 auto;"><a href="http://kutsalkitap.org/kilise-adresleri/"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-107" src="http://kutsalkitap.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Chapel-Icon.png" alt="kilise-bul" width="128" height="128" /><br />Kilise <br />Adresleri</a></div>

  <div style="margin:0 auto;"><a href="http://kutsalkitap.org/online-kutsal-kitap/"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-107" src="http://kutsalkitap.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Bible-Icon.png" alt="online-kutsal-kitap" width="128" height="128"/><br />Online <br />Kutsal Kitap</a></div>

</div>
```

and here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yjwo2eqa/

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Giving `text-align: center;` to the top most `div` fixes it:

```
<div style="margin-left: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
```

**Preview**

[image]

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h3ckLfx1/**

Comment: Hi Praveen,Thanks for you help. Can i make them look like this in mobile, but side-by-side on desktop?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="text-align:center">

  <div style="margin:0 auto;"> <a href="http://kutsalkitap.org/category/tartisma/"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-107" src="http://kutsalkitap.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Blog-Icon.png" alt="tartisma-blog" width="128" height="128" /><br />Tartışma <br />Blog</a></div>

  <div style="margin:0 auto;"><a href="http://kutsalkitap.org/kaynaklar/"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-107" src="http://kutsalkitap.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Gift-Icon.png" alt="hediyeler-kaynaklar" width="128" height="128" /><br />Hediyeler <br />ve Kaynaklar</a></div>

  <div style="margin:0 auto;"><a href="http://kutsalkitap.org/kilise-adresleri/"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-107" src="http://kutsalkitap.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Chapel-Icon.png" alt="kilise-bul" width="128" height="128" /><br />Kilise <br />Adresleri</a></div>

  <div style="margin:0 auto;"><a href="http://kutsalkitap.org/online-kutsal-kitap/"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-107" src="http://kutsalkitap.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Bible-Icon.png" alt="online-kutsal-kitap" width="128" height="128"/><br />Online <br />Kutsal Kitap</a></div>

</div>
```

`margin-left` is not required just add `text-align:center`

Comment: Gaurav, thanks for you help. Can i make them look like this in mobile, but side-by-side on desktop?

Comment: @media queries are there in css to handle in mobile... `@media (max-width:767px){//your code here}` 767px and below width is generally for mobile and tablets. you can write css here to customize looks in mobile